# How to convert a string taken out from a Ruby array into a C/C++ String

Tags: c++, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I rm writing a C++ extension for Ruby, and am trying to extract a Ruby string object out of a Ruby array object, and convert it to a C/C++ string object.

I have **foo.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ruby.h>

VALUE bar_func(VALUE self, VALUE ary){
    std::string s = StringValuePtr(rb_ary_entry(ary, 0));
    ...
    return 0;
}

extern "C" VALUE rb_cFoo;
VALUE rb_cFoo;
extern "C" void Init_foo(){
    rb_cFoo = rb_define_class("Foo", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cFoo, "bar", RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(bar_func), 1);
}
```

and **test.rb**:

```
require "foo"
Foo.bar(["Hello World!"])
```

When I try to compile `foo.cpp`, the compiler returns an error saying something like *"a single term & operand needs left side value"* (not exact message. translated from an error message given in another natural lauguage). It's regarding my usage of `StringValuePtr`. What am I doing wrong, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: reference operator `&` should use *left-hand value*, i.e. couldn't be applied to constants.

Comment: @kirilloid Is there a way to fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`StringValuePtr` does not return a null-terminated C string](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT#L122) suitable for the [assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/). You should use the `StringValueCStr` macro, which also takes a `VALUE` as parameter.

[`StringValueCStr`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L472) is defined as follows:

```
#define StringValueCStr(v) rb_string_value_cstr(&(v))
```

The [`rb_string_value_cstr`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L1440) function signature is:

```
char * rb_string_value_cstr(volatile VALUE *ptr)
```

After macro expansion, your code should look like this:

```
std::string s = rb_string_value_cstr(&rb_ary_entry(ary, 0));
```

Your code doesn't look wrong to me. Try putting each part in separate lines to see if you can narrow down the origin of the error:

```
VALUE entry = rb_ary_entry(ary, 0);
char * c_str = StringValueCStr(entry);
std::string str = c_str;
```